# application is locked malloc -> OSSpinLockLock$VARIANT$mp

Tags: ios, xcode, locking, malloc, deadlock

My iphone app get locked malloc. If I press `pause` button in Xcode it pauses in OSSpinLockLock$VARIANT$mp function.

```
#0  0x95dfbc2d in OSSpinLockLock$VARIANT$mp ()
#1  0x95dc2613 in szone_malloc_should_clear ()
#2  0x95dc366b in szone_malloc ()
#3  0x95df9962 in malloc_zone_malloc ()
#4  0x95dfa882 in malloc ()
#5  0x0219743a in operator new(unsigned long) ()
```

if I press `continue` and then `pause` again then it always shows same stack trace.

Comment: That suggests that you've corrupted the heap. Or perhaps that some thread was terminated by a signal while it held the lock.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your other threads. One of them is likely blocked inside of a malloc or free as well and the two are deadlocked against each other.

A somewhat common cause of this is allocating memory inside of a signal handler (which you should never do). You'll see this especially if you have some kind of "crash catcher" in your system, and inside of the handler you do complex operations.

Comment: I am not sure what is signal handler. I think I am not using it. (Is it function that process SIGABRT, etc) I use Facebook SDK. When I press pause I see only 1 suspended thread in xcode. It is always C++ code called from Facebook callback function. If it was dead lock then I could expect to pause one of 2 threads but not always first or second. I hope you understand. Right now I can't reproduces but it happened 3 times in morning and I saw it few times before. So some problem exists. Thank You

Comment: It is very surprising that there would only be a single thread, particularly with the Facebook API running. I would expect at least 5. Look at their stacks and see if they've also called SpinLock at some point. Yes, a signal handler would be something for SIGABRT and the like.